# Which books to read to grasp Philosophy from scratch?

Tags: reference-request

I have recently joined this beautiful community to explore Philosophy with full enthusiasm. I have gone through several great threads and loved this field of interest.

However, I could not digest the fact that: there are no threads related to *A Beginner's Guide and Books to Understanding Philosophy* or something similar.

Rather than asking Google and getting random answers, I prefer relying on the great teachers here for the best Philosophy books to read.

Comment: Go to stanford enclyopedia of philosophy and start reading one article everyday or two... you'll get it something eventually...

Comment: [Will Durant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Philosophy)  is an accessible general intro. And Socrates/Plato is perennial accessible and was universally accepted as the fountainhead of all (western) philosophy — at least until recently

Comment: @SBrian Wow, it's a world in itself!

Comment: @Rusi Got the PDF edition. Thanks!